# Rechart.js decrease space between bottom text (Months)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, recharts

I almost make chart, that i need. Now i make this in Rechart.js
[image: My chart]

I must do this

[image: Hiw it must be]

An i have a few questions

1. How i can decrease space between bottom text (jun,dec etc...) in Rechart.js
2. How i can shift the starting point, for example, by 20 pixels, without shrinking the line
3. How i can customize vertical line when hover ( change color, style, height etc )

If you know at least 1 answer l'll be very thankful

Thank you for any information about this

Comment: please consider that ask a question and focus on it in your post. multiple questions are not acceptable from the Stackoverflow commiunity.

Comment: and what did you do so far?
please share with us your workout, code snippets, error logs, or any useful information, good luck .

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.